# Git grep of past version

Tags: git, grep

If I had a string `foo` I wanted to grep for, and wanted to search a past version `decafbad` for it, what `git-grep` command would I do to search for it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could just do like below:

```
# git grep <regexp> <revison>
git grep foo decafbad
```

If you want to search in all versions:

```
git grep <regexp> $(git rev-list --all)
```

If you want to search between two versions:

```
git grep <regexp> $(git rev-list <revison1>..<revison2>)
```

Comment: +1. Don't forget quotation marks around the pattern string (foo) if involves characters like whitespace.